# How to cast ComObject to ENVDTE.Project?

Tags: c#, envdte

I am using the following code :

```
Object projObj = htProjects[selectedNode]; // htProjects is a Hashtable:key-project Name,value-ENVDTE.Project
Project selectedProject = (Project)projObj;
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I tried registering DLLS as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354007/visual-studio-2008-publish-fails-cant-load-dll-envdte-dll) but there seems to be some other issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. Some hashtable entries had ENVDTE.ProjectItems as value. So a check was needed.

Code:

```
        if (projObj is Project)
        {
            Project selectedProject = (Project)projObj;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedProject.FullName);
        }
        else if(projObj is ProjectItem)
        {
            ProjectItem selectedProject = (ProjectItem)projObj;
            MessageBox.Show(selectedProject.get_FileNames(1));
        }
```