# How to cast ComObject to ENVDTE.Project for Unmodeled projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins, envdte

My question is very similar to this one: [How to cast ComObject to ENVDTE.Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291769/how-to-cast-comobject-to-envdte-project)

I want to process the Project items selected in Visual Studio -> Solution Explorer. If project is loaded the code works fine but I have troubles for unloaded projects (they are called Unmodeled projects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw7ek4f4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Casting selected item for loaded projects **uiItem.Object is EnvDTE.Project** is fine, but how to cast Unmodeled projects?
There is no 'UnmodeledProject' class and casting **uiItem.Object is ProjectItem** does not work.

This is my code:

```
Window solutionExplorer = mApplicationObject.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer);
if(solutionExplorer != null)
{
    UIHierarchy uiHierarchy = (UIHierarchy)solutionExplorer.Object;
    if (uiHierarchy != null)
    {
        object[] selectedItems = (object[])uiHierarchy.SelectedItems;
        foreach (UIHierarchyItem uiItem in selectedItems)
        {                              
            // Valid project
            if (uiItem.Object is EnvDTE.Project)
            {
                EnvDTE.Project project = uiItem.Object as EnvDTE.Project;
                if (project.FullName.Contains(".vdproj") || project.Kind == "{54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C}")
                {

                }
            }
            else if (uiItem.Object is ProjectItem)
            {
              // This is never jumped...
            }
            else
            {  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I did not find a solution for this situation I used this trick:

```
string pathToVdProject = null;
try
{
    Window solutionExplorer = mApplicationObject.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer);
    if (solutionExplorer != null)
    {
        UIHierarchy uiHierarchy = (UIHierarchy)solutionExplorer.Object;
        if (uiHierarchy != null)
        {
            object[] selectedItems = (object[])uiHierarchy.SelectedItems;
            foreach (UIHierarchyItem uiItem in selectedItems)
            {
                // Valid project
                if (uiItem.Object is EnvDTE.Project)
                {
                    EnvDTE.Project project = uiItem.Object as EnvDTE.Project;
                    if (project.FullName.Contains(".vdproj") || project.UniqueName.Contains(".vdproj")
                        || (String.Compare(project.Kind, ProjectsGuids.guidVdSetupProject, true) == 0))                                    
                    {
                        // Valid Project has property FullName which is full path to .vdproj file
                        pathToVdProject = project.FullName;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (uiItem.Object is ProjectItem)
                {
                    // This never happens...
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is a little tricky: Unmodeled Projects cannot be casted to EnvDTE.Project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw7ek4f4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx 
                    Solution2 solution = (Solution2)mApplicationObject.Solution;

                    // So get all projects in solution (including unmodeled) and try to find a match by name
                    foreach (Project project in solution.Projects)
                    {
                        if (project.Kind == EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindUnmodeled)
                        {
                            // Unmodeled project found (Normal projects are recognized in 'uiItem.Object is EnvDTE.Project'
                            if (project.Name.Contains(uiItem.Name))
                            {
                                // This is 'Project' for selected item
                                if (project.Name.Contains(".vdproj") || project.UniqueName.Contains(".vdproj"))
                                {
                                    // Unmodeled projects does not offer property FullName and UniqueName does NOT contain full path to file!
                                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(solution.FullName);

                                    // Create full path from solution (.sln) path and project relative path
                                    pathToVdProject = fileInfo.DirectoryName + "\\" + project.UniqueName;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

List of all loaded/Unloaded projects inside the solution explorer will be available in your EnvDTE application object. Without using solution Explorer window and UIHierarchy i got the project details. Below code snippets working fine for me. Please check out weather it will fit for you..

```
For Each item As EnvDTE.Project In mApplicationObject.Solution.Projects
     If item.Globals Is Nothing AndAlso item.Object Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + "  is currently unloaded!")
     End If
Next
```

Comment: No, this is way I do not want to go. I want to recognize Class of a selected item, but thanks for this comment.